# Not able to execute groovy script from command ".GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions."

Tags: groovy, version, mismatch

I have run groovy script for a while from command line. Recently I have started to work with spock/groovy in the eclipse. I have run couple of test using Groovy Console when console was loaded from eclipse. Any way after these activities I have tried to execute groovy from command line and it failed with the following error:

Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-xml is loaded in version 2.4.3 and you are trying to load version 2.4.1

I was using gvm tool to reinstall groovy and set is a primary version but still have the problem. Something was changed from eclipse where my groovy installation gets affected and can not be fixed by by reinstalling.

I have some search done but did not find solution. most solution were mentioning this problem but they were trying to fix this withing eclipse, where in my case I am trying to fix it outside of eclipse. Also will be nice if I be able to prevent this from happening in the future. If somebody have similar experience please share.

Thanks,
Alexander